# bind9 build from source : how to set install/config directory

Tags: bind, configure

I have built and installed bind from source (https://github.com/isc-projects/bind9). This has installed to `/usr/local/sbin` and is expecting configuration files to be in `/usr/local/etc`.

I have copied the contents of my current `/etc/bind` to `/usr/local/etc` and modified copies of the systemd service files named `bind*` to use the `/use/local/sbin/named` executables and now I have the new bind installation running successfully.

I'm just guessing at the set up and I welcome corrections -- but I'm posting because I want to use the configuration directory `/etc/bind` in place: to avoid the problems of redundancy and so on.

I have looked into the `configure` file of the build directory and see the section below that looks like the place to set values as I want them. Is this correct? And if so, what values would I set to achieve what I want?

```
    bindir='${exec_prefix}/bin'
    sbindir='${exec_prefix}/sbin'
    libexecdir='${exec_prefix}/libexec'
    datarootdir='${prefix}/share'
    datadir='${datarootdir}'
    sysconfdir='${prefix}/etc'
    sharedstatedir='${prefix}/com'
    localstatedir='${prefix}/var'
    includedir='${prefix}/include'
    oldincludedir='/usr/include'
    docdir='${datarootdir}/doc/${PACKAGE_TARNAME}'
    infodir='${datarootdir}/info'
    htmldir='${docdir}'
    dvidir='${docdir}'
    pdfdir='${docdir}'
    psdir='${docdir}'
    libdir='${exec_prefix}/lib'
    localedir='${datarootdir}/locale'
    mandir='${datarootdir}/man'
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3239343/make-install-but-not-to-default-directories#3239373

Comment: @ajgringo619 Ah yes. That will be a help.

Comment: @ajgringo619 It does not help.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't completely understand what you wanted. In combination with moving the install to another folder besides /usr/local - something like ./configure --prefix=/somewhere/else/than/usr/local - you'll need to make a symlink afterwards that connects /etc/bind to ${prefix}/etc/bind.

Comment: Stephen or ajgringo619, is there a solution here? (Please make an Answer, even a self-answer, if there is). Thanks!